# DASM directives/pseudops

Tags: assembly, 6502

I'm looking through the documentation and there are a few pseudo ops that I am stuck with, they are `DV`, `LIST` and `XXX`.

`DV` says is like `DC` but used with `EQM`, I've mess around with it, but I am not noticing any difference, I've try to find any examples but couldn't find any.

`LIST` and `XXX`, I'm not sure how these works either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## DV

`DV` does macro expansion. This is best demonstrated with an example.

```
mymacro  eqm    10 + ..

mylist   dv     mymacro 1, 2, 3
```

The first line defines a symbol `mymacro` that will be used as a macro. The dotdot (`..`) acts as a parameter.

In the second line, the macro is applied to every expression in the list. From left to right:

- 1 is replaced by 10 + 1
- 2 is replaced by 10 + 2
- 3 is replaced by 10 + 3

Basically, the second line is equivalent to:

```
mylist   dc     10 + 1, 10 + 2, 10 + 3
```

which obviously is equivalent to:

```
mylist   dc     11, 12, 13
```

The example is rather trivial; `DV` may be more useful when the macro contains a symbol.
For example:

```
mylabel  dc     "ABCD"
mymacro  eqm    mylabel + ..
mylist   dv     mymacro 1, 2, 3
```

is equivalent to:

```
mylabel  dc     "ABCD"
mylist   dc     mylabel + 1, mylabel + 2, mylabel + 3
```

## LIST

`LIST OFF` and `LIST ON` affect output being written to the list file.
Normally, every line from the source file is written to the list file; this is inhibited by `LIST OFF`. Error messages will still be written to the list file, though.

Obviously, this only has effect if a list file was specified on the command line (option `-l` or `-L`).

## XXX

As far as I can tell, DASM has no pseudop `XXX`.
I guess you are refering to this part of [the documentation](https://github.com/munsie/dasm/blob/master/doc/dasm.txt):

```
[label] XXX[.force] operand
```

`XXX` is just a placeholder there; it can be any mnemonic you like, for example `lda`.
See the section about the FORCE extension.

Comment: Fantastic reply, i have another question,  the LIST directive, which list is turning on or off? The only list I'm aware of is the symbol list.

Comment: @DanielSega Please feel free to edit your original question and add `LIST` and other pseudops that are unclear; I will gladly expand my answer accordingly.